# Reverse Engineering Panasonic IR Code Checksum

Tags: arduino, reverse-engineering, checksum

I'm working on a *Panasonic AC Unit* which is controlled by a *IR remote*. The remote sends `12 bytes`.

The first `5 bytes` are always identical. The following `6 bytes` correspond to air conditioner temperature, fan, function and other options which I was able to figure out myself.

The last `byte` is a *checksum* that is somehow obtained from the first `11 bytes` (or from *byte* `6` to `11`)

Since I re-create the *IR codes* at runtime, I need to be able to compute *checksum* for these packets.  I tried with many standard checksum algorithms, none of them gave meaningful results.

Could you help me finding out the *checksum function* used for this device?

---

Here is a list of *packets*, composed by `11 bytes` of header+data and `1 byte` of checksum, that I was able to *capture* from the device:

```cpp
40 00 14 81 25 00 A0 65 00 00 00 26
40 00 14 81 25 00 A0 68 00 00 07 30
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 65 00 00 00 2A
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 68 00 00 00 2D
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 68 00 00 02 2F
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 68 00 00 03 30
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 68 00 00 04 31
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 68 00 00 05 32
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 68 00 00 07 34
40 00 14 81 25 04 28 69 00 00 01 2F
40 00 14 81 25 04 A0 68 00 00 07 34
40 00 14 81 25 08 9A 68 00 00 07 41
40 00 14 81 25 08 9C 68 00 00 07 43
40 00 14 81 25 08 9E 68 00 00 07 45
40 00 14 81 25 08 A0 68 00 00 00 31
40 00 14 81 25 08 A0 68 00 00 01 32
40 00 14 81 25 08 A0 68 00 00 02 33
40 00 14 81 25 08 A0 68 00 00 03 34
40 00 14 81 25 08 A0 68 00 00 07 38
40 00 14 81 25 08 A2 68 00 00 07 3A
40 00 14 81 25 08 A4 68 00 00 07 3C
40 00 14 81 25 08 A6 68 00 00 07 3E
40 00 14 81 25 08 A8 68 00 00 07 40
40 00 14 81 25 08 AA 68 00 00 07 42
40 00 14 81 25 08 AC 68 00 00 07 44
40 00 14 81 25 08 AE 68 00 00 07 46
40 00 14 81 25 09 A0 68 00 00 07 39
40 00 14 81 25 0A A0 68 00 00 07 3A
40 00 14 81 25 0C A0 68 00 00 07 3C
40 00 14 81 25 40 18 65 00 00 00 29
40 00 14 81 25 40 1A 65 00 00 00 2B
40 00 14 81 25 40 1C 65 00 00 00 2D
40 00 14 81 25 40 1E 65 00 00 00 2F
40 00 14 81 25 40 20 65 00 00 00 22
40 00 14 81 25 40 22 65 00 00 00 24
40 00 14 81 25 40 24 65 00 00 00 26
40 00 14 81 25 40 26 65 00 00 00 28
40 00 14 81 25 40 28 65 00 00 00 2A
40 00 14 81 25 40 2A 65 00 00 00 2C
40 00 14 81 25 40 2C 65 00 00 00 2E
40 00 14 81 25 40 2E 65 00 00 00 30
40 00 14 81 25 40 30 65 00 00 00 23
40 00 14 81 25 40 32 65 00 00 00 25
40 00 14 81 25 40 34 65 00 00 00 27
40 00 14 81 25 40 34 68 00 00 04 2E
40 00 14 81 25 80 1C 68 00 00 00 34
40 00 14 81 25 80 20 65 00 00 00 26
40 00 14 81 25 C0 20 65 00 00 00 2A
40 00 14 81 25 C0 28 68 00 00 02 37
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a candidate *checksum function* which matches **all** of your data, but I think that further adjustments are needed, because I suspect that the **magic number** I use depends on *something else* which I did not properly take into account.

---

This is the function that I was able to *reverse engineer*:

```c
uint8_t get_checksum(const uint8_t data[], const size_t size)
{
    assert(data);

    uint8_t checksum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        checksum += (data[i] >> 4) + (data[i] & 0x0f);
    }

    checksum -= 8; /* magic number */

    return checksum;
};
```

An alternative version:

```c
uint8_t get_checksum(const uint8_t data[], const size_t size)
{
    assert(data);

    uint8_t checksum = 0xF8; /* magic number */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        checksum += (data[i] >> 4) + (data[i] & 0x0f);
    }

    return checksum;
};
```

---

**Example:**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<assert.h>

uint8_t get_checksum(const uint8_t data[], const size_t size)
{
    assert(data);

    uint8_t checksum = 0xF8; /* magic number */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        checksum += (data[i] >> 4) + (data[i] & 0x0f);
    }

    return checksum;
};

int main ()
{
    const size_t xlen = 49;
    const size_t ylen = 12;
    uint8_t v[49][12] = {
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x00,0xA0,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x26},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x00,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x30},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2A},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2D},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x2F},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x30},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x31},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x32},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x34},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0x28,0x69,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x2F},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x04,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x34},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0x9A,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x41},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0x9C,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x43},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0x9E,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x45},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x31},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x32},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x33},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x34},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x38},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA2,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x3A},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA4,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x3C},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA6,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x3E},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xA8,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x40},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xAA,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x42},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xAC,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x44},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x08,0xAE,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x46},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x09,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x39},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x0A,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x3A},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x0C,0xA0,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x3C},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x18,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x29},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x1A,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2B},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x1C,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2D},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x1E,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2F},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x20,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x22},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x22,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x24},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x24,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x26},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x26,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x28},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x28,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2A},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x2A,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2C},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x2C,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2E},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x2E,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x30,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x23},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x32,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x25},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x34,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x27},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x40,0x34,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x2E},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x80,0x1C,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x34},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0x80,0x20,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x26},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0xC0,0x20,0x65,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2A},
        {0x40,0x00,0x14,0x81,0x25,0xC0,0x28,0x68,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x37}
    };

    // packet has 11 bytes, 1 byte is for the checksum
    for (size_t i = 0; i < xlen; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t checksum = get_checksum(v[i], 11);

        printf("result: %02x -- should be: %02x -- %s\n",
               checksum, v[i][ylen - 1],
               (checksum - v[i][ylen - 1] == 0 ? "OK" : "ERROR"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```c
result: 26 -- should be: 26 -- OK
result: 30 -- should be: 30 -- OK
result: 2a -- should be: 2a -- OK
result: 2d -- should be: 2d -- OK
result: 2f -- should be: 2f -- OK
result: 30 -- should be: 30 -- OK
result: 31 -- should be: 31 -- OK
result: 32 -- should be: 32 -- OK
result: 34 -- should be: 34 -- OK
result: 2f -- should be: 2f -- OK
result: 34 -- should be: 34 -- OK
result: 41 -- should be: 41 -- OK
result: 43 -- should be: 43 -- OK
result: 45 -- should be: 45 -- OK
result: 31 -- should be: 31 -- OK
result: 32 -- should be: 32 -- OK
result: 33 -- should be: 33 -- OK
result: 34 -- should be: 34 -- OK
result: 38 -- should be: 38 -- OK
result: 3a -- should be: 3a -- OK
result: 3c -- should be: 3c -- OK
result: 3e -- should be: 3e -- OK
result: 40 -- should be: 40 -- OK
result: 42 -- should be: 42 -- OK
result: 44 -- should be: 44 -- OK
result: 46 -- should be: 46 -- OK
result: 39 -- should be: 39 -- OK
result: 3a -- should be: 3a -- OK
result: 3c -- should be: 3c -- OK
result: 29 -- should be: 29 -- OK
result: 2b -- should be: 2b -- OK
result: 2d -- should be: 2d -- OK
result: 2f -- should be: 2f -- OK
result: 22 -- should be: 22 -- OK
result: 24 -- should be: 24 -- OK
result: 26 -- should be: 26 -- OK
result: 28 -- should be: 28 -- OK
result: 2a -- should be: 2a -- OK
result: 2c -- should be: 2c -- OK
result: 2e -- should be: 2e -- OK
result: 30 -- should be: 30 -- OK
result: 23 -- should be: 23 -- OK
result: 25 -- should be: 25 -- OK
result: 27 -- should be: 27 -- OK
result: 2e -- should be: 2e -- OK
result: 34 -- should be: 34 -- OK
result: 26 -- should be: 26 -- OK
result: 2a -- should be: 2a -- OK
result: 37 -- should be: 37 -- OK
```

Comment: @SIAV glad it helps, if you are able to produce more samples and come up with a wrong result please update your question and *add a comment here*, so I can fix my answer.